# Intercept API calls of powershell module

Tags: proxy, active-directory, azure, powershell

I am looking at a way to intercept the API call made by the [AzureAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/overview?view=azureadps-2.0) powershell module. Wireshark is not able to decrypt the TLS packets sent and I'd also like to work with the HTTP requests rather than single packets.

So my question is: is there a way to use a tool like Burp (or any equivalent program) to act as proxy between the Powershell and the Microsoft server in order to see which APIs are called upon executing a module command?

Any help is highly appreciated.